# Where is SigningCertificate and RequireSsl in AddIdentityServer method identity server4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

According to [this](http://elemarjr.com/en/2016/04/18/learning-identityserver4-part-1-securing-an-webapi/) article i can access `SigningCertificate`  and `RequireSsl`  in `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class:

```
 var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.SigningCertificate = certificate;
            options.RequireSsl = false; 
        });
```

I do as it said but i got error:

> 'IdentityServerOptions' does not contain a definition for 'SigningCertificate' and no extension method 'SigningCertificate' accepting a first argument of type 'IdentityServerOptions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   NewIdentityServer..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0  2015\Projects\NewIdentityServer\src\NewIdentityServer\Startup.cs

how can i access these properties?

NOTE: I use  identity server version:  `"IdentityServer4": "1.1.0",`

Answer (score 0):

These are not properties on the  is not`IdentityServerOptions` (your options) but on they are extension methods on the `IIdentityServerBuilder` (your builder).

There are a few overloads of the `AddSigningCredential()`, you should check which one works best for you.

But an example could be:

`var builder = services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(certificate);`